# Select all the pairs of people which never worked together but which both worked with a third person

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So, let's try to make this simple.
Let's say I have three tables (I am gonna post here just the useful attributes of interest):

```
DEVELOPERS( dev_id, ...)
COLLABORATIONS( activity_id, dev_id, ... )
ACTIVITY( activity_id, ...)
```

Collaborations is a table used to link all the Activities done to the Developers who worked on them (it's primary key is the pair `activity_id, dev_id`). The important part is that on one single Activity could have worked a minimum of 1 dev but an undefined maximum of them (no restrictions)

What I need to know, and I am finding hard to grasp how, is the `dev_id`s of all the pairs (and only pairs) of developers which never worked together (aka there are no tuples of Collaborations with same activity_id and both their dev_id)  BUT, both of them, worked with (at least one) same "third developer" in some other Collaboration

I need to get as a result a table of rows in which there are two columns containing every single pair of devs that satisfy the requirements.

NOTE that I am not asking to check only the collaboration with two devs working on them, but every single one of them.

My first idea was to first find all the Developers who worked together, remove their dev_id (maybe with an except?) from the list of all Developers (so I have only those who never collaborated within themselves) and start from there.

Any idea or suggestions?

Adding example for clarification:

```
activity_id     dev_id
1               2
1               3
1               5

2               1
2               3

3               1
3               4
3               2
```

So here for example the dev 3 and 4 never worked together, but both worked with at least another same dev ( dev 1 and dev 2 in this case)

Dev 1 and 5 never worked together but both worked with at least another same dev (dev 3 and dev 2 in this case)

Dev 4 and dev 5 never worked together but both worked with at least another same dev (dev 2 in this case)

so the query should return

```
devA    devB
3       4
1       5
4       5
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Where is your attempt? Are you looking for someone who will work for you for free?

Comment: @KoshVery That's why I asked for "ideas or suggestions", and not a ready-on solution. I am really stuck because I have no idea how to proceed to be able to make this sort of comparison in sql (I am not used to work with db, I am a frontend guy). I would be fairly happy with an answer sort of "these type of comparisons are done by blabla and blabla, got the idea?" and then I would try without posting gibberish

Comment: This reads very much like a an assignment question in an intro to database course

Comment: Please tag accurately. Which database is this actually for? `Postgres <> MySQL` they have different features and syntax. Choose just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very straightforward approach

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.dev_id, d.dev_id
FROM COLLABORATIONS AS a
JOIN COLLABORATIONS AS b ON a.activity_id = b.activity_id AND a.dev_id<>b.dev_id
JOIN COLLABORATIONS AS c ON b.dev_id = c.dev_id
JOIN COLLABORATIONS AS d ON c.activity_id = d.activity_id AND c.dev_id<>d.dev_id
WHERE a.dev_id<d.dev_id

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT a.dev_id, b.dev_id
FROM COLLABORATIONS AS a
JOIN COLLABORATIONS AS b ON a.activity_id = b.activity_id AND a.dev_id<b.dev_id

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

It takes all pairs that are connected through third person a substracts all direct pairs. As mysql does not support EXCEPT, you would have to replace it, I would leave it as an exercise.

Comment: You can use `MINUS` instead of `EXCEPT` in `MYSQL`. Is your query support more than 3 activities also ? if it is, then it will work fine.

Comment: @Susang if that has not changed lately, mysql does not support MINUS either.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone will be able to improve on this but I think it works (see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20203/40)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.dev_id, 
    d.dev_id
FROM 
    COLLABORATIONS c, 
    DEVELOPERS d
WHERE 
    c.dev_id > d.dev_id AND
    (
    SELECT 
        ca.activity_id 
    FROM 
        COLLABORATIONS ca 
    WHERE 
        ca.dev_id = c.dev_id AND 
        ca.activity_id  IN 
        (
        SELECT 
            cb.activity_id 
        FROM 
            COLLABORATIONS cb 
        WHERE cb.dev_id = d.dev_id
        ) 
    LIMIT 1) IS NULL AND
(
SELECT 
    cc.dev_id 
FROM 
    COLLABORATIONS cc 
WHERE 
    cc.activity_id IN
    (
    SELECT 
        cd.activity_id 
    FROM 
        COLLABORATIONS cd 
    WHERE 
        cd.dev_id = c.dev_id) AND 
        cc.dev_id IN 
        (
        SELECT 
            ce.dev_id 
        FROM 
            COLLABORATIONS ce 
        WHERE 
            ce.activity_id IN
            (
            SELECT 
                cf.activity_id 
            FROM 
                COLLABORATIONS cf 
            WHERE 
                cf.dev_id = d.dev_id)
            )  
    LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: If you replace COLLABORATIONS c with DEVELOPERS c to remove duplicities it works. But the performance seems suboptimal, I tested it on mssql and it was 15min vs 23sec for join solution on my sample.